# mysql trigger change before update

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I need to change a column before update. this is my trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER select_for_update BEFORE UPDATE ON conductor
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE first_frame1 varchar(255);
if NEW.video_id <> OLD.video_id THEN

select first_frame into first_frame1 from video where id_video=NEW.video_id;
SET NEW.first_frame=first_frame1;

END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

but I receive this error:

> This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

how can i resolve this problem.

Comment: Looks like you already have a trigger defined on that table and can't add another one. Drop the first one if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had defined a trigger on that table. Kindly drop the trigger and then again execute the newly trigger. It will definitely gave no error.